# Restrict ciphers in embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, security, tomcat, embedded-tomcat-7, embedded-tomcat-8

How can I programmatically restrict the available ciphers in embedded Tomcat?

In other words what is the programmatic equivalent of

`<connector ciphers="...">`

Comment: What does your driver code look like already? Are you manually configuring a `Connector`?

Comment: Yes, I am configuring a connector

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that's a setting that doesn't have a direct `Connector.set*Foo*` method. Try this:

```
Connector conn = ...;
conn.setProperty("Ciphers", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, ...");
```

If you are using Tomcat 8, you can also use [OpenSSL syntax](http://openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html#CIPHER-SUITE-NAMES), even when using a JSSE-based connector. See the "Ciphers" section of http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html for more information.